# Nextjs - Correct way to add auth access for catch-all routes

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, routes

I’m not sure if “catch all” would be the correct term here, but how do you block access to page routes (not API) including any slug that comes after the first slug. Also, I’m using Nextjs and NextAuth

Ie. Allow all-auth-users access but not public access to:
/account/userid

Ie. Allow only logged in session user access to:
/account/userid/actions

Ie. Still only allow logged in session user access to:
/account/userid/actions/create

The only way I can think of doing this is by detecting router paths via useRouter and then adding specific wrapper components with session logic around /account/userid/ and different session logic for around /account/userid/actions.

Is this the correct/best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a `middleware.ts` file and define which routes you wish users to have access to. More on nextjs middleware here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware. And as for authorization of each route via middleware, you can read more about that here https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs

Comment: When I say routes, I’m saying page routes, not API routes. Do those links still apply?

Comment: Yep, middleware can run on any route that you define in your pages dir